# Spam bots hitting user/register non cached pages generate load, how to prevent?

Tags: performance, advertising, 7

I have SpamBot installed, still bots can hit the user/register page that is not cached by Boost and generate load if they do it recursively. Any tips to prevent them?
Or, the only solution is http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page?

Comment: Add some type of captcha.

Comment: A CAPTCHA will help with SPAM registrations, but they will still do a HTTP request and cause load on the server.

Comment: you could add some code to IP block any spammer. Also checkout http://drupal.org/project/honeypot

Comment: honeypot looks good! As well as botcha.